# Decompiling lua

Tags: lua, decompiling

Here is a small (126 Bytes) example file called `yeha.luac`. Opened with my editor, it looks something like

```
LJB   4    >4   >G  get_object_baseget_ket4   1   5  G  $
```

But all decompilers give out errors. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As those tools indicated that's not compiled lua bytecode.

Lua bytecode has a `Lua` tag in it.

```
$ echo | luac5.1 -o - - | cat -v; echo
^[LuaQ^@^A^D^H^D^H^@^G^@^@^@^@^@^@^@=stdin^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^B^B^A^@^@^@^^^@M-^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

That bytecode has an `LJ` tag. That is luajit bytecode.

```
$ echo | luajit -b -t raw - - | cat -v; echo
^[LJ^A^B^K^B^@^A^@^@^@^AG^@^A^@^@
```

Comment: luajit bytecode is, as I recall, much more optimized and has a variety of output formats (that, as indicated by `-t raw`, is the "raw" output format).

Comment: @Blauhirn Offhand, no idea. At a guess I'd say some application "customizing" their dump tag for some reason. Where did you get it from?